# HIGHSLIDE JS : fixed position of the gallery

Tags: highslide

I'm using Highslide for show some images on my website. 
Look here to know what I'm using : http://highslide.com

I use autoloading because I want just see the popup without the gallery. It seems to work fine. But I want it to stay in the same place no matter where I am in the page.

How can I fix the popup of my highslide galery (like a div in a relative position) ?

I try it with targetX & targetY elements but that works just when I load the page; when I click on an other image, the popup "follows" the size of the page.

My site is not online but check my code here :
In the head of my page :

```
<head>
<!--HIGHSLIDE - GALERIE D'IMAGES -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo "http://".CHEMIN_HIGHSLIDE."highslide-full.js"; ?>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo "http://".CHEMIN_HIGHSLIDE."highslide.config.js"; ?>" charset="utf-8"></script>       
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo "http://".CHEMIN_HIGHSLIDE."highslide.css"; ?>" />
    <!--[if lt IE 7]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo "http://".CHEMIN_HIGHSLIDE."highslide-ie6.css"; ?>" />
    <![endif]-->
<script type="text/javascript">          
<!--HIGHSLIDE GALERIE-->
    //GLOBAL
        hs.graphicsDir = 'highslide/graphics/';
        hs.align = 'center';           
        hs.showCredits = true;
        hs.outlineType = null;
        hs.expandDuration = 0;//ms
        hs.outlineWhileAnimating = 1;
        hs.padToMinWidth = true;
        hs.width = 700;
        hs.height = 480;
        hs.allowMultipleInstances = false;
        hs.blockRightClick = true;
        hs.captionOverlay.position = 'above';
        hs.headingEval = 'this.thumb.title';
        hs.targetX = null; //null dc suit le flux
        hs.targetY ='target 5px'; // div="target", 5px à droite
    //FRENCH language strings
    hs.lang = {
        cssDirection: 'ltr',
        loadingText: 'Chargement...',
        loadingTitle: 'Cliquer pour annuler',
        creditsText: 'Propulsé par <i>Highslide JS</i>',
        creditsTitle: 'Site Web de Highslide JS',
        previousText: 'Précédente',
        nextText: 'Suivante',
        moveText: 'Déplacer',
        playText: 'Lancer',
        playTitle: 'Lancer le diaporama (barre d\'espace)',
        pauseText: 'Pause',
        pauseTitle: 'Suspendre le diaporama (barre d\'espace)',
        previousTitle: 'Précédente (flèche gauche)',
        nextTitle: 'Suivante (flèche droite)',
        restoreTitle: 'Utiliser les touches flèches droite et gauche pour suivant et précédent.'
    }; 
//AUTOLOAD     
    // Open the first image on page load
    hs.addEventListener(window, "load", function() {       
        // click the element virtually:
            document.getElementById("autoload").onclick();
    });    
    // Prevent closing the image when clicking the dimmed background
    hs.onDimmerClick = function() {
        return false;
    }
    // Keep the position after window resize
    hs.addEventListener(window, 'resize', function() {
        var i, exp;
        hs.page = hs.getPageSize();
        for (i = 0; i < hs.expanders.length; i++) {
            exp = hs.expanders[i];
            if (exp) {
                var x = exp.x,
                    y = exp.y;
                // get new thumb positions
                exp.tpos = hs.getPosition(exp.el);
                x.calcThumb();
                y.calcThumb();
                // calculate new popup position
                x.pos = x.tpos - x.cb + x.tb;
                x.scroll = hs.page.scrollLeft;
                x.clientSize = hs.page.width;
                y.pos = y.tpos - y.cb + y.tb;
                y.scroll = hs.page.scrollTop;
                y.clientSize = hs.page.height;
                exp.justify(x, true);
                exp.justify(y, true);
                // set new left and top to wrapper and outline
                exp.moveTo(x.pos, y.pos);
            }
        }
    });    
    // Cancel the default action for image click and do next instead
    hs.Expander.prototype.onImageClick = function (sender) {
        return hs.next();
    }
        var galleryOptions = {
            slideshowGroup: 'group1',
            transitions: ['expand', 'crossfade']
        }; 
        // Add the slideshow providing the controlbar and the thumbstrip
        hs.addSlideshow({
            slideshowGroup: 'group1',
            interval: 3000,
            repeat: true,
            useControls: true,
            fixedControls: 'fit',
            overlayOptions: {
                opacity: 0.85,
                position: 'bottom center',
                relativeTo: 'image',
                offsetX: 0,
                offsetY: 5,
                hideOnMouseOut: true
            },
            thumbstrip: {
                mode: 'horizontal',
                position: 'below',
                relativeTo: 'image'
            }
        });
        //place for the thumbstrip
        hs.Expander.prototype.onInit = function() {
           hs.marginBottom = (this.slideshowGroup == 'group1') ? 105 : 15;
        };
</script>
<title>Titre</title>
```

In the body :

```
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="content">
        <div id="en_tete">
            header
        </div>
        <div id="contenu">
            <div id="target">
                //target for the place of highslide gallery in the page
            </div>
            <div class="highslide-gallery">
            <?php
                //array of images to show (I keep it otherwhere)
                $array=array(
                    array('nom'=>'image 1','lien'=>'link_img_1','txt'=>'Text sup image 1'),
                    array('nom'=>'image 2','lien'=>'link_img_2','txt'=>'Text sup image 2'),
                    array('nom'=>'image 3','lien'=>'link_img_3','txt'=>'Text sup image 3')
                );
                //...
                if(isset($array))
                {
                    $nb=sizeof($array);

                    $i=1; 
                    //HIDDING THUMBNAILS
                    echo '<div id="highslide-html" class="hidden-container">';
                        foreach($array as $arr)
                        {
                            echo '<a href="'.IGES.'big/'.$arr['lien'].'.png" 
                                     id="'.(($i===1) ? 'autoload' : '').'"
                                     class="highslide" 
                                     onclick="return hs.expand(this, galleryOptions);">
                                    <img src="'.IGES.'minia/'.$arr['lien'].'.png" alt="" 
                                            title="'.mettre_1ere_en_maj($arr['nom']).'"/>
                                </a>
                                  <span class="highslide-caption">
                                    '.$arr['txt'].'
                                  </span>';
                            $i++;
                        }
                    echo '</div>';
                }
            ?>
            </div>
        <!--ferm contenu-->
        </div>
    <!--ferm content-->
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        <div id="footer_container">
            footer
        </div>
    <!--ferm footer-->
    </div>
<!--ferm container-->
</div>
```

I really searched the internet. I found some things, but everything is in English, and although I do understand a little, there are many things I do not understand.

I have also seen such a function to be integrated so that targetX & targetY work but I really do not know where.

```
onclick = "return hs.htmlExpand (this, {contentId: 'highslide-html' targetX: null, targetY 'target 0px', height: 700, width: 480})"
```

May anyone help me please?

Comment: I am not able to get your exact requirement. Can your please explain a bit what exactly you want? Do you want a Popup or a tooltip box? You can also have a look into this library http://jquerytools.org/

Comment: thanks for your answer. I would like use a popup gallery of highslide like a div in relative position. You know better what I want to say ?

Comment: In my case, I would have in a div in my webpage a big image and a little gallery of all my images bellow (thumbnails) with the next and preview button. Wen you clic on one of them, the big image change, like the thumbnail below wich shows the image selected (a border around, a small arrow below the selected thumbnail or something like that). I chose highslide because it does exactly what I want with transparency effects and perfect flow.You see?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the "in-page gallery" examples on this page will get you steered in the right direction:

http://www.roadrash.no/?page_id=11